# node express with docker-compose returns 502 bad gateway

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

My application is working. console.log is recorded on logs, and able to display process.env.URL on cmd. However, on the browser, it returns error 502, bad gateway.

This is my docker-compose

```
version: "2"

volumes: 
  mongostorage:

services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - "3000"
    links:
      - mongo
      - redis
    command: node ./bin/www
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - app:app
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
    volumes:
      - mongostorage:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

nginx.conf

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http{
    upstream app.dev{
        least_conn;
        server app:3000 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app.dev;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

This is app/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:6.3

WORKDIR /var/www/app

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/app

COPY package.json /var/www/app

RUN npm install

COPY . /var/www/app
```

This is nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest

EXPOSE 80

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your nginx.conf file, In proxy_pass_http you should use the server name i.e

`proxy_pass http://app.dev/` instead of `proxy_pass http://app` and it should work;

Comment: It shows this error on cmd: 2017/11/04 11:16:01 [error] 5#5: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: app.dev, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.21.0.4:3000/favicon.ico", host: "app.dev", referrer: "http://app.dev/"

Comment: Make sure you remove the existing image of ngnix from your local machine and start the compose system again. It should work fine

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Same error message occurred as above and 502 Bad Gateway on browser

Comment: It works for me i have verified it with docker-compose version 1.13.0,

Comment: it is working dy. Thanks. Any idea on getting it to run multuple apps with different port with the same docker-compose file and nginx configure?